# Error: Argument 1 must have names. when using map_drf in r

Tags: r, purrr

I have a list of `datasets` that all contain one column of `timestamps`, however, these `timestamps` are not ordered from the first `timepoint` to the last. I want to order this column in each `dataset` using `map_dfr` with a function.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)

temp = list.files(pattern="*.csv")
myfiles = lapply(temp, read.csv)
## there is now a list of 45 dataframes called myfiles

func <- function(x){
  ordsyn <- sort(x$synergytst, na.last = TRUE) ## column synergytst contains 
  #disordered timestamps
}

purrr::map_dfr(myfiles, func)

## Error: Argument 1 must have names.
```

This code returns an Error:

> "Error: Argument 1 must have names."

What does this mean ?

Comment: Your function is not returning anything.  It would be `return(ordsyn)`, but it is again a vector and not a named vector

Answer (score 2):

from what I understood you want to sort or arrange the individual dataframes inside the list by the date colum, while binding to a `dataframe` by row. For this `sort()` is a not the right aproach as it returns a `vector` according to the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/sort).

On possible way to solve your task is this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

# dummy data as plain character data
ml <- list(df1 = data.frame(a = c("2021-01-01", "2020-01-01", "2022-01-01"), 
                            b = 4:6),
           df2 = data.frame(a = c("2021-01-01", "2020-01-01", "2022-01-01"), 
                            b = 1:3))

purrr::map_dfr(ml, ~.x %>%  
                       # convert column of interest to Date
                       dplyr::mutate(a = as.Date(a)) %>%
                       # order by column
                       dplyr::arrange(a))

           a b
1 2020-01-01 5
2 2021-01-01 4
3 2022-01-01 6
4 2020-01-01 2
5 2021-01-01 1
6 2022-01-01 3
```

Possibly you want to identify the files but are not able to, after binding to one `data.frame`. One nice solution for this can be de usage of named lists and the `plyr::ldply` function:

```
library(plyr)

# name the dummy list items created above with a sequential numeric vector 
 names(ml) <- 1:length(ml) # you could use your temp variable as well to name the list items

# bind to list using list names as id column
plyr::ldply(ml) %>%
    # convert column of interest to Date
    dplyr::mutate(a = as.Date(a)) %>%
    # arrange by id and after this by column a
    dplyr::arrange(.id, a)

  .id          a b
1   1 2020-01-01 5
2   1 2021-01-01 4
3   1 2022-01-01 6
4   2 2020-01-01 2
5   2 2021-01-01 1
6   2 2022-01-01 3
```